# PHP error_reporting not effective

Tags: php, apache

Having set PHP (8.1) error reporting to:

`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE);`

I still see [php:notice] in apache2 error log: /var/log/apache2/error.log

e.g.

`[Thu Dec 01 06:22:08.479832 2022] [php:notice] [pid 331848] [client 172.70.211.134:64910] You have attempted to register a duplicate item with WooCommerce Navigation:` checkout-form`, referer: https://www.testdomain.com/wp-admin/`

What am I missing?

When I call error_log(...) in my PHP code, what log severity level is it mapped to apache's error log?

Comment: are you sure you edited the right `php.ini`?

Comment: Added log entry, yes I am sure and I have verified it with this tool https://maximivanov.github.io/php-error-reporting-calculator/ it calculates to 8183 which is the error_reporting() call sets.

Comment: I am asking if you edited the `php.ini` that apache module reads and not i.e. the one used of cli version. Run `phpinfo()` on apache and check if shown path matches the file you altered. Also you should be able to see what `error_reporting` is really set from module's perspective.

Comment: I set error_reporting in real time with error_reporting().

Comment: Besides, setting it in /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini and restarted apache doesn't seem to take effect. Still seeing [PHP:notice] from /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Comment: The log message is produced from WooCommerce source code, specifically this line: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/src/Admin/Features/Navigation/Menu.php#L226 which is a general error_log() call.

Comment: Where are you calling `error_reporting()`? You can try `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE)` in your wp-config.php file

Comment: I am calling error_reporting() from my child theme's functions.php file. And I just tried using init_set() in both files, no dice.

Comment: I suspect that error_reporting does not supress explicit error_log() calls.

Comment: https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/177036-solved-trigger_error-vs-error_log/#:~:text=the%20error_log%20function%20will%20perform%20its%20duties%20regardless%20of%20the%20value%20set%20in%20the%20log_errors%20ini%20setting.%20It%20does%20not%20raise%20a%20PHP%20error%2C%20so%20it%20does%20not%20have%20a%20severity%20level

Answer (score 0):

The `error_reporting` controls PHP logging, yet in this particular case `error_log()` function is called to explicitly log something. This cannot be muted using `error_reporting()`. If you do not want that error either fix the cause of comment out that particular PHP line or configure your logger to drop such message. But from technical PoV this actually works as intended, however it could be looking bit confusing at first glance.